# Javascript Object destructuring syntax confusion

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fairly new to javascript and have been working my way through a course on React.

Can anyone help me to understand how the object destructuring code works? the other two are quite straight forward but the syntax of the last one leads me confused as to how the local variables work?

[image]

Comment: this is roughly equivalent to `let {target} = event;` which sets a variable (in this case a parameter) called `target` to the value of `event.target`

Comment: Please don't make code photos, instead paste it into the question as text and format it as code. It could be hard to copy paste your code in future questions.

Comment: You can even do `const {target:{value}} = event` which will be equivalent to: `const value = event.target.value`